# How to calculate the sum of column score and time

Tags: c#

I have a 2-dimensional array like below.
If I want to sum all time and score of rows of Each ID that start from lesson `startpoint`=`E` and ends by lesson `endspoint`=`I`. In the case below, for ID 1 it become (time=190+195+200=585 and score=3+3+4=10) and ID 3 that (time=190+210+160=560 and score=5+4+4=13).

I already came up with following loop.

```
 ID Lesson  Time    Score
    1   C   165 4
    1   E   190 3
    1   H   195 3
    1   I   200 4
    2   A   100 2
    2   B   150 5
    2   D   210 2
    2   E   110 4
    3   D   130 5
    3   E   190 5
    3   H   210 4
    3   I   160 4
    3   J   110 4
    4   E   120 3
    4   H   150 4
    4   J   170 4
```

-

```
for (int i=0; i<SizeofDataGrid;i++)//save datatable into array
{
     for (int j=0; j<4;j++)
     {
         FILTERED[i,j]=Convert.ToString(interaction.Rows[i][j]);
     }
}     
for (int i = 0; i < FILTERED.GetLength(0); i++)
         {
         string UNIQUEID = UniqueUserId[i];
         for (int j = 0; j < SizeofDataGrid; j++)
         {  
             if (UNIQUEID == FILTERED[j,0])// match ID
             {
                  for (int x = 0; x < SizeofDataGrid; x++)
                  {
                      if (startpoint == FILTERED[j, 1]) //Match start Lesson
                      {
                      TotalTime[1, i] = TotalTime[1, i] + Convert.ToUInt16(FILTERED[j, 2]);
                      TotalTime[0, i] = i;
                      TotalScore[1, i] = TotalScore[1, i] + Convert.ToUInt16(FILTERED[j, 3]);
                      TotalScore[0, i] = i;
                      }
                  }
             }
        }

        }
```

Comment: How is your array/grid stored? Does your code not work? If yes then what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Hello @Nasreddine. My code works but the point is how I can break the loop when it get to the target point(I). I mean, I need to save the time and records from the target point also and then break the loop.my array is [Grid.Rows.Count,4]

Comment: Your array stores both ints and chars? please post the actual definition of the array.

Comment: @Nasreddine, I edit the code. The array is there right now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// this method does the calculations then puts the values in the totalScore and totaltime variables
public void DoCalculations(string[,] data, string id, out int totalScore, out int totalTime)
{
    totalTime = 0;
    totalScore = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (data[i, 0] != id) continue;

        // modify this string to contain the lessons between E and I
        if (!"EFGHI".Contains(data[i, 1])) continue;

        // do proper error checking unless you're sure they'll always be integers
        totalTime += int.Parse(data[i, 2]);
        totalScore += int.Parse(data[i, 3]);
    }
}
```

And this is the usage example:

```
string[,] data = new string[,]
{
    {"1",   "C",   "165", "4"},
    {"1",   "E",   "190", "3"},
    {"1",   "H",   "195", "3"},
    {"1",   "I",   "200", "4"},
    {"2",   "A",   "100", "2"},
    {"2",   "B",   "150", "5"},
    {"2",   "D",   "210", "2"},
    {"2",   "E",   "110", "4"},
    {"3",   "D",   "130", "5"},
    {"3",   "E",   "190", "5"},
    {"3",   "H",   "210", "4"},
    {"3",   "I",   "160", "4"},
    {"3",   "J",   "110", "4"},
    {"4",   "E",   "120", "3"},
    {"4",   "H",   "150", "4"},
    {"4",   "J",   "170", "4"}
};

// will store the total score
int totalScore = 0;
// will store the total time
int totalTime = 0;
// calling the function for the id=3
DoCalculations(data, "3", out totalScore, out totalTime);

Console.WriteLine(totalTime); // will output: 560
Console.WriteLine(totalScore); // will output: 13
```

Comment: Thanks @Nasreddine. But I could not understand this part > if `(!"EFGHI".Contains(data[i, 1])) continue;` May you explain how it works?

Comment: @pedrojorge I used that to calculate the score and time of the line when the lesson is `E`, `F`, `G`, `H` or `I` (basically between `E` and `I`) as per your requirements.

Comment: @nasreaddine. Thanks, Then if i change it to something like 'if (!"E*I".Contains(data[i, 1])) continue;', should it work?, since i do not know how many many records are between E and I?

Comment: It wont work. If they are just letters and they are alphabetically ordered then you can leave it as is. If you want to specify a range the you could use `if(!Regex.IsMatch(data[i, 1],"[A-Z]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) continue;` then replace `A-Z` with the desired range of letters.

Comment: since I have 'startpoint' and 'targetpoint' which are dynamic as instead of the fixed values ("[A-Z]"). Then I should write something like "startpoint-targetpoint" or ['startpoint'+'targetpoint'] ?

Comment: Yes, provided that they are letter ordered alphabetically. (A-E, E-O. etc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the `break` statement? You should be able to create a conditional statement that checks for your condition, then put `break;` at the bottom of it and you will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using `string[,] FILTERED` to store your data. You really can easily create strong data types instead. However, if you must use it then I would convert to a strong data type and then do the calculations.

So, starting with the raw data:

```
string[,] FILTERED = new string[16, 4]
{
    { "1", "C", "165", "4" },
    { "1", "E", "190", "3" },
    { "1", "H", "195", "3" },
    { "1", "I", "200", "4" },
    { "2", "A", "100", "2" },
    { "2", "B", "150", "5" },
    { "2", "D", "210", "2" },
    { "2", "E", "110", "4" },
    { "3", "D", "130", "5" },
    { "3", "E", "190", "5" },
    { "3", "H", "210", "4" },
    { "3", "I", "160", "4" },
    { "3", "J", "110", "4" },
    { "4", "E", "120", "3" },
    { "4", "H", "150", "4" },
    { "4", "J", "170", "4" },
};
```

I would first turn this into strongly-type data:

```
var data = 
    FILTERED
        .Cast<string>()
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .GroupBy(xn => xn.n / 4, xn => xn.x)
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            ID = int.Parse(xs.ElementAt(0)),
            Lession = xs.ElementAt(1),
            Time = int.Parse(xs.ElementAt(2)),
            Score = int.Parse(xs.ElementAt(3)),
        });
```

This gives:

[image: data]

I would then do this query:

```
var result =
    data
        .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            ID = xs.Key,
            Lessions = xs
                .Where(x => x.Lession.Intersect("EFGHI").Any())
                .ToArray(),
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            Time = x.Lessions.Sum(y => y.Time),
            Score = x.Lessions.Sum(y => y.Score),
        })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me this result:

[image: result]

Now, just as an alternative to mucking around with the intermediate `FILTERED` array you could just get the data directly from the `DataTable` like this:

```
var data =
    from row in interaction.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    select new 
    {
        ID = row.Field<int>(0),
        Lession = row.Field<string>(1),
        Time = row.Field<int>(2),
        Score = row.Field<int>(3),
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is I need to sum the time and score from E to I, and having E or I should not be my outcome. For example, based on the reult table that you put there, the result for  ID 1 and 3 is fine but it should not calculate anything for ID 2 and 4, since these 2 IDs do not have both lesson(E and I).

Comment: @pedrojorge - So, if I understand you correctly you only wish to sum those with **both** `E` & `I`, and, if that's true, then you only wish to sum the values if they have `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, & `I`?

Comment: @pedrojorge - Or is it the case that your data was misleading and that you want to sum the values between and including `E` & `I`, regardless of the `Lession` values between?

Comment: @ Enigmativity, thanks again.  If an ID has two specific lessons ('E' and 'I' are just examples), I need to extract the ID that has these two lessons. I already did that part. Now, for the detected IDs I need to calculate the sum for the time and score that starts from the record with 'E' lesson for that ID and ends by the record that has 'I' for the lesson. Then for this data, ID 2 and 4 will be ignored since they do not have 'I' lesson and for ID 1 and 3 the result should be like follw. ID 1:(time=190+195+200=585 and score=3+3+4=10) and ID 3 (time=190+210+160=560 and score=5+4+4=13).

Comment: @pedrojorge - Could there be multiple `E` & `I` pairs per `ID`?